# Set Pop UP window size,width,height automatically to center based on content kept in pop up message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my JavaScript requirement I am having popup display on loading page which  popup message content will change frequently.

**Now what I want is,**

I want to show popup at center of window which automatically sets the height, width, size of popup.

Example: If I have single small sentence in message content, It should display small size popup align to center like `Message.Box` in C# windows application.

If I have large/huge data, automatically it should stretch to minimum size (Width: 500px; Height: 500px) with scroll bars horizontal and vertical.

I tried in Google, but not getting exactly what I want.

Is there any formulas to do this?

My sample Calculation which aligns to center: (Its working fine only for display pop up center but not auto size/width/height/scrollbars)

```
var top = $(window).height() / 2 - popupContainer.height() / 2, //Vertically Center to screen
    left = $(window).width() / 2 - popupContainer.width() / 2; //Horizontally center to screen
```

Comment: maybe add some code?

Comment: I updated post by adding my sample code. pls. refer that